# Use 12 unit length matchsticks to enclose a region whose area is 4 square units

Tags: matches

I do not know the original source of this problem; I have seen it a few places.  The solution that I have seen is not pretty in the sense that it lacks symmetry.  Can you find an elegant solution?  Of course, elegance is subjective.

User Stiv asked if the answer must be a single region.  I will allow answers that consist of multiple regions.

Comment: Does it have to be a *single* region? Because two separate rectangles springs to mind...

Comment: @Stiv  I will allow multiple regions.

Comment: Does this puzzle "invite speculative answers"? Yes. That is its *intention*. Should it remain open? I say yes because it is interesting, and I'm totally fine that there are many "correct" answers. The answers posted so far are all great! However, there are other types of puzzles that "invite speculative answers" that should be closed -- overly-vague riddles come to mind.

Comment: A one-by-four rectangle takes only 10 unit lines. What am I missing?

Comment: @keshlam In my question you have to use all 12 matchsticks.  So, for example, a two-by-two square (area = 4) would not be a valid solution because it only uses 8 matchsticks.

Comment: @JLee Thank you for your support of my question.

Comment: I wondered if anyone has suggested a "don't" close response and [they have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close).

Comment: If you want to keep it open, edit it to define the problem better. For example, as posed I can make my 10-stick solution into a 12-stick one by stacking the last two on top of sticks in the outline, or just pointing them off into nowhere so they don't enclose any space... Or just by dropping them across the middle of the box... or using them to offset part of the box, which I would argue meets not only the letter but the intent of the problem as posed. If there's a good puzzle here, it can be posed more clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a very simple solution:

> Make a parallelogram with base 4 and height 1, as shown:
>  [image: image of parallelogram]
>
>  Here, you can see that the distance from $A$ to $C$ is 2 units (since the black circle has radius 2, and $\overline{AC}$ is just another radius). Similarly, $\overline{BD}$ has length 2; so you can place 4 matchsticks along the top and bottom, and 2 on the two diagonals.
>
>  (This, of course, generalizes to any area from 0 to 8 - you just have to change the angles of the parallelogram.)

Comment: Cool!  And simple!

Answer (score 8):

The funny thing about this problem is that once you understand the sticks don't have to follow a square grid, you see that you can enclose any surface up to 9 and some units by just making any loop and adjusting the space between the matches, flattening the figure, until it encloses the right surface.

I will try for "elegant".

> [image: ![paralellogram with sides 1 and 5]
>
>  According to Pythagoras the diagonals are 5 units.
>  This gives a perimeter of 2x5 + 2x1 = 12.
>  The suface is the base times the height, 1x4 = 4.

Comment: This is a nice solution.

Answer (score 7):

Using 12 matches to obtain an area of 4 units:

> [image]
>
>  Four regions but squarely square.

**Edit**: another distinct solution with a single enclosed area:

> Based on the 3:4:5 Pythagorean triangle, and very easy to construct.
>  It would normally have perimeter = 12, area = 6 units.
>  But moving 3 matches at the right-angle reduces the area by 2 units.
>  So it now has **perimeter = 12, area = 4 units**.
>
>  [image]

Comment: A nice simple answer.

Comment: I like it.  One might wonder whether you twist the rules, but you definitely have enclosed 4 unit squares.

Comment: @FlorianF thanks. I realise that in effect I was 'hiding' four matches but the rules say "answers that consist of multiple regions". I had looked at a Pythagorean 3:4:5 possibility too, but your answer got it nicely.

Comment: If you use the four internal matches to create a single square inside, would the whole figure be enclosing only three unit squares?

Comment: @Muqo a shape with a hole in it? There's an idea. Not that but I have added another (fully legal) solution to this answer.

Answer (score 6):

One area, some symmetry, and easy to create from a square:

> [image]

Comment: @ParclyTaxel If you fold one part inwards, you have to fold another part outwards to stay at area 4.

Comment: Another nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

If the matchsticks do not need to form one *single* enclosed region, and instead the areas of multiple enclosed regions can be combined to sum to an area of 4 square units, there are two more trivial solutions:

> [image: Two trivial solutions]
>
>  In fact, any arrangement where you can form four unit squares from sixteen matches, and then combine them in a way so as to remove four of them will provide a valid answer.

Comment: Another nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the most symmetric solution:

> a six-pointed star à la Twilight Sparkle.
>  [image]
>  The inner vertices form a regular hexagon with side length $2s$, where $s=0.4107231313\dots$ solves $6s(s\sqrt3+\sqrt{1-s^2})=4$.

Comment: Nice solution & diagram

Comment: Considering that you answered this question, why did you vote to close the question?

Comment: One reason for closing a question is when it has too many solutions.  And this one does have many solutions.  I myself did not vote to close it though because it still gets people stumped because they are looking for a solution based on squares.

Comment: @FlorianF Before posting I knew there were at least two solutions.  I hope people had fun trying to solve this puzzle.  I think some solvers would be happy to find even one solution while other solvers would want to find as many solutions as possible.